# "Autosave" Functionality in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript

I'd like to add an "autosave" feature to a Reagent form in a ClojureScript function. In Clojure, I usually make something out of a `ScheduledExecutorService`. Since that isn't available in ClojureScript, I came up with the following.

```
(def delay-handle (atom nil))

(defn clear-autosave-delay! []
  (.clearTimeout js/window @delay-handle))

(defn start-autosave-delay!
  [doc-save-fn delay-ms page-map-atom]
  (reset! delay-handle (.setTimeout js/window doc-save-fn delay-ms page-map-atom)))

(defn change-watcher!
  [doc-save-fn page-map-atom]
  (let [delay (* 1000 (get-in @page-map-atom [:options :editor_autosave_interval]))]
    (when (pos? delay)
      (clear-autosave-delay!)
      (start-autosave-delay! doc-save-fn delay page-map-atom))))
```

I put the `change-watcher!` function in the Reagent `:on-change` handlers for the input controls. Whenever a change occurs, it resets the delay. If the delay expires, the `doc-save-fn` is called to do the save.

It seems to work Ok, but isn't very "Clojuresque." Is there a more idiomatic way to write this?​

Comment: I don't think there's really anything that wrong with this. Thin wrappers over ugly interop aren't that uncommon. That's the sole purpose of a good deal of Clojure libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Use debouncer for this issue. It's pretty simple and does same

```
(goog.functions.debounce auto-save-action 1000)
```